# PC seems to think every certificate is invalid?

Tags: firefox, google-chrome, internet-explorer

My PC has been acting pretty funny lately, literally claiming that every web certificate I come across is invalid. I've even reformatted the thing, and I continue to have the problem. This is across IE, Firefox, and Chrome? What's going on and how can I fix it?

Comment: Is there a possibility that somebody is intercepting your communications?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Make sure your computer's clock is set correctly. X.509 certificates have "start" and "expire" dates.
- Open the same website on two different computers (the other can be at work, school, whatever) and compare the certificate information (subject, issuer, fingerprint).

Comment: you got the check dude, deleting the comments now, thx for finding a reason instead of just -1ing me

Comment: Thank you, feel a little dumb for not noticing...but my clock was set back to 2003. Appreciate the helpful answer.